# Mysql Stored Procedure - Select and update multiple rows of the same table

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE table1
(id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
,tag VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
,tag2 VARCHAR(20) NULL
,var1 VARCHAR(20) NULL
,external_tags TINYINT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO table1 VALUES
(1, 'school_signup_xxx', NULL, NULL, 0), 
(2, 'course_enroll_213', NULL, NULL, 0), 
(3, 'external_tag1', NULL, NULL, 1  ), 
(4, 'external_tag2', NULL, NULL, 1);
```

I have to update each rows in this table so that value in **tag** field should be split to **tag2** and **var1** fields.

So, I want to update each rows in the table **table1** as below

```
1, school_signup_xxx, school_signup, xxx, 0  
2, course_enroll_213, course_enroll, 213, 0  
3, external_tag1, external_tag1, NULL, 1  
4, external_tag2, external_tag1, NULL, 1
```

That means if **external_tags** is 0, then split **school_signup_xxx** to **school_signup** and **xxx** and update these values in **tag2 and var1** fields respectively.

if **external_tags** is 1, then update value in **tag** field to **tag2** field.

There about 600,000,000 records in my table2 and have to update each row according to the value in external_tags column value.

As stored procedure is fast for such mass data moving purpose, please help me to write a **stored procedure in MYSQL** for the above case.

Comment: I see nothing 'procedural' here.

Comment: Then how can I update 6 crores records fastly?

Comment: Please don't use words that are only used locally in your country, like "crore". People aren't going to understand you.

Comment: @JamesZ To be fair, the word (or similar) *is* used by 1.5 billion people

Comment: @radocaw And how many of them live outside that region?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot see that a sproc confers any advantage here:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS table1;

CREATE TABLE table1
(id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
,tag VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
,tag2 VARCHAR(20) NULL
,var1 VARCHAR(20) NULL
,external_tags TINYINT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO table1 VALUES
(1, 'school_signup_xxx', NULL, NULL, 0), 
(2, 'course_enroll_213', NULL, NULL, 0), 
(3, 'external_tag1', NULL, NULL, 1  ), 
(4, 'external_tag2', NULL, NULL, 1);  

SELECT *
     , SUBSTRING_INDEX(tag,'_',2) x 
     , SUBSTRING_INDEX(tag,'_',-1) y 
  FROM table1
 WHERE external_tags = 0;
  
+----+-------------------+------+------+---------------+---------------+-----+
| id | tag               | tag2 | var1 | external_tags | x             | y   |
+----+-------------------+------+------+---------------+---------------+-----+
|  1 | school_signup_xxx | NULL | NULL |             0 | school_signup | xxx |
|  2 | course_enroll_213 | NULL | NULL |             0 | course_enroll | 213 |
+----+-------------------+------+------+---------------+---------------+-----+
```

...so...

```
UPDATE table1 
  SET tag2 =  SUBSTRING_INDEX(tag,'_',2)
    , var1 = SUBSTRING_INDEX(tag,'_',-1)
WHERE external_tags = 0;

Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.004 sec)
Rows matched: 2  Changed: 2  Warnings: 0

SELECT * FROM table1;
+----+-------------------+---------------+------+---------------+
| id | tag               | tag2          | var1 | external_tags |
+----+-------------------+---------------+------+---------------+
|  1 | school_signup_xxx | school_signup | xxx  |             0 |
|  2 | course_enroll_213 | course_enroll | 213  |             0 |
|  3 | external_tag1     | NULL          | NULL |             1 |
|  4 | external_tag2     | NULL          | NULL |             1 |
+----+-------------------+---------------+------+---------------+
4 rows in set (0.000 sec)
```

Comment: In my case there will be not only school_signup_xxx, course_enroll_bbb but also other patterns like automation_notify_bounced_111_222 - in this case move automation_notify_bounced to tag2, 111 to var1, 222 to var2. Another data pattern will be registered_live_co_host_111_ls_schedule_222. In this case registered_live_co_host should be moved to tag2, 111 to var1 and 222 to var2. Actually there are tag, tag2, var1, var2, external_tags fields. There are millions of records and is live data and data are inserted into this table all the times. Need Fastest method to move data to tag2, var1, var2.

Comment: Actually there are tag, tag2, var1, var2, external_tags fields. The value in tag field will be of different pattern like school_signup_x, course_enroll_b, automation_notify_bounced_1_2, registered_livestream_co_host_1_ls_schedule_2, attended_live_class_1_schedule_2 etc. For last case attended_live_class_1_schedule_2, attended_live_class should be moved to tag2, 1 to var1, 2 to var2. So records in each row are of different patterns. There are millions of records and is live data and data are inserted into this table all the times. I want a fastest method to move data to tag2, var1, var2.

Comment: Garbage In,  Garbage Out, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
UPDATE table1
SET tag2 = SUBSTRING_INDEX(tag, '_', 2),
    var1 = SUBSTRING(tag FROM LENGTH(tag2) + 2 FOR LENGTH(tag));
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2f427df477804ef900b6460872d13c8c

or (taking into account `external_tags` value)

```sql
UPDATE table1
SET tag2 = SUBSTRING_INDEX(tag, '_', 2),
    var1 = CASE WHEN external_tags
                THEN var1
                ELSE SUBSTRING(tag FROM LENGTH(tag2) + 2 FOR LENGTH(tag))
                END;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=74cab81b232e79631688f7efe20e4a6f

Comment: In my case there will be not only school_signup_xxx, course_enroll_bbb but also other patterns like automation_notify_bounced_111_222 - in this case move automation_notify_bounced to tag2, 111 to var1, 222 to var2. Another data pattern will be registered_live_co_host_111_ls_schedule_222. In this case registered_live_co_host should be moved to tag2, 111 to var1 and 222 to var2. Actually there are tag, tag2, var1, var2, external_tags fields. There are millions of records and is live data and data are inserted into this table all the times. Need Fastest method to move data to tag2, var1, var2.

Comment: Actually there are tag, tag2, var1, var2, external_tags fields. The value in tag field will be of different pattern like school_signup_x, course_enroll_b, automation_notify_bounced_1_2, registered_livestream_co_host_1_ls_schedule_2, attended_live_class_1_schedule_2 etc. For last case attended_live_class_1_schedule_2, attended_live_class should be moved to tag2, 1 to var1, 2 to var2. So records in each row are of different patterns. There are millions of records and is live data and data are inserted into this table all the times. I want a fastest method to move data to tag2, var1, var2.

Comment: @Renji You simply must create an expression which selects according extractional sub-expression for each separate data pattern based on the value format and, maybe, another columns values (`external_tags`, for example). Like in my 2nd query... *Need Fastest method to move data to tag2, var1, var2.* Single query is faster than SP. PS. XY-problem.

Comment: So can you please help me for the update query to single update if tag value (actual value is registered_live_co_host_111_ls_schedule_222) contain the string registered_live_co_host and if external_tags is 0, then update tag2 field to registered_live_co_host and var1 field to 111 and var2 field to 222 ?

Comment: @Renji You must formulate complete parsing rules list firstly.

Comment: I have 5 cases

1. If external_tags = 0 and tag = course_enrolled_{var1value} then update tag2 to course_enrolled and var1 to var1value
2. If external_tags = 0 and tag = automation_notify_bounced_{var1value}_{var2value} then update tag2 to automation_notify_bounced and var1 to var1value and var2 to var2value

Comment: 3. If external_tags = 0 and tag = registered_livestream_co_host_{var1value}_schedule_{var2value} then update tag2 to registered_livestream_co_host and var1 to var1value and var2 to var2value
4. If external_tags = 0 and tag = attended_recurring_live_class_{var1value}_rec_schedule_{var2value} then update tag2 to attended_recurring_live_class and var1 to var1value and var2 to var2value
5. If external_tags = 1 then update tag2 to tag value